# Animate Div If Visible jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no clue anything relating to jQuery. Completely new to this. I am trying to make divs with a class of `#animated` slide in from the bottom when the page is scrolled and the div comes into view. I copied this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  (function($) {

    /**
     * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
     * Licensed under the MIT license.
     * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
     *
     * @author Sam Sehnert
     * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
     *     the user visible viewport of a web browser.
     *     only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
     */

    $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

      var $t = $(this),
        $w = $(window),
        viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
        viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
        _top = $t.offset().top,
        _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
        compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

      return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

    };

  })(jQuery);

  var win = $(window);

  var allMods = $(".module");

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("already-visible");
    }
  });

  win.scroll(function(event) {

    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
      var el = $(el);
      if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("come-in");
      }
    });

  });

});
```

From a website but the code does not work. I did not change anything at all. The code does not do what it is [supposed to do](https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/)

So now I don't know what to do. I downloaded the jQuery library and linked it with *script* and then went back to my main 
.js. My text editor ([Adobe Brackets](http://www.brackets.io)) gave me errors (50 of them)

So my question is what am I doing wrong. BTW My CSS is flawless, I know CSS and HTML but don't know about jQuery and HTMl together as in importing that type of code, if that makes sense.

EDIT: My HTML And CSS If you need it.

```css
/* Slide In */

@import "compass/css3";
 * {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
.animated {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.come-in {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}
.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
}
@keyframes come-in {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
/* Background */

#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
/* Header */

#headerbg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.79);
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  /* Header */
  #header {
    margin-left: 10%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 730px) {
  #header {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  #header {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #header {
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
}
/* Navigation */

nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  /* Makes links on the same line */
}
nav a {
  margin: 0 5px;
  /* Space out the words */
  color: #151413;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  padding-bottom: 0.125em;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.75s linear 0s;
  font-weight: 600;
}
@media (min-width: 350px) {
  nav a {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin: 0 12px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  nav a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  nav {
    padding-top: 48px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  nav a {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  nav {
    padding-top: 52px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  nav a {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  nav a {
    margin: 0 15px;
  }
  nav {
    padding-top: 56px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  nav {
    margin-right: 20%;
  }
}
nav a:hover,
nav a.active {
  border-bottom-color: #151413;
  color: #151413;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}
/* About */

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 140px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (min-width: 350px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 145px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 360px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 150px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 160px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 510px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 170px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 180px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 130px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 140px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 150px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 155px;
  }
}
#about {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  p {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
#aboutbar {
  background-color: #151413;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #aboutbar {
    background-color: #151413;
    height: 5px;
    width: 56.6666666667%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
/* Managers */

#managersbg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 475px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.79)
}
@media (min-width: 340px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 445px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 350px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 450px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 360px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 455px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 365px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 435px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 417px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 485px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 400px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 510px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 475px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 624px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 455px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 460px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 674px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 435px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 778px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 415px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 425px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 914px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 405px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
#screamer,
#swezii,
#kinzu {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#screamer {
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
#swezii {
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
#managers {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#manager1,
#manager2,
#manager3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
#manager1 {
  top: -410px;
}
#manager2 {
  top: -220px;
}
#manager3 {
  top: -60px;
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #manager1,
  #manager2,
  #manager3 {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
#text1,
#text2 {
  margin-bottom: 110px;
}
#text1,
#text2,
#text3 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#text1 {
  top: -450px;
}
#text2 {
  top: -420px;
}
#text3 {
  top: -370px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TheVersionArts Studio</title>
  <meta name="description" content="TheVersionArts is a private design studio. We provide clients with quality design at a small cost.">
  <meta name="author" content="TheVersionArts">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- CSS
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">

  <!-- Favicon
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

  <!-- Scripts
 -------------------------------------------------- -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
 –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <img src="images/bg.png" id="background">

  <div id="headerbg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="five columns">
          <img src="images/thv-header.png" id="header">
        </div>
        <div class="seven columns">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#designers">Designers</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutbg">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
          <h4 id="about">About Us</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="twelve columns">
            <p>TheVersionArts is a private design studio. We were founded in the winter of 2014. We connect clients to the designers they need. Our goal is to serve high quality design at an affordable price through the internet. We strive to impress our
              clients. We don't sell graphics, or designs. We sell art and colours.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns" id="aboutbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="managersbg">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <h4 id="managers">Our Managers</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column" id="screamer">
          </div>
          <div class="one-third-column" id="swezii">
          </div>
          <div class="one-third-column" id="kinzu">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <p id="manager1">Screamer</p>
          </div>
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <p id="manager2">Swezii</p>
          </div>
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <p id="manager3">KINZU</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">
            <p id="text1">I am a guy who loves to get the things in my head onto paper. I have some great ideas that will blow your minds! Get ready!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">
            <p id="text2">I love Web, App and other designing. It is my goal to get rid of bad design in my city.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">
            <p id="text3">I'm that guy chilling on his computer, creating fantastic art for you.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class in the jQuery here: `var allMods = $(".module");` should be `var allMods = $(".animated");` – that should work.

Comment: So I change just the .module to .animated, I deleted .module because it looked like it was just styling in CSS. And .animated class used to be .section

Comment: This did not work. I changed only .module to .animated.

Comment: Well, what the code does is: It looks up every element with the class `.module` and works with them and only them. So you need to tell the browser to not look for `.module`, but for `.animated`. That will do the trick. Check this Codepen (or rather the source code via inspector), the classes get attached while scrolling: http://codepen.io/HerrBertling/pen/rVwXew

Comment: There is no animation when I change, save and refresh the page.

Comment: I know. The classes do get attached when scrolling, though, so probably something is wrong with the CSS.

Comment: Your pen works but when I copy the code into my document it does not animate it.

Comment: Please check first if the classes are actually applied to your HTML code. They should be. If that's the case: Check your CSS animations, they seem to not work then.

Comment: The problem was that I had not imported my script correctly. Thanks so much for you help!